# DateTimePicker WinForm: Set value when validating updates value incorrectly

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datetimepicker

I have a problem with DateTimePicker, which was quite easy to reproduce, and feels like a bug in the control itself, but I wanted to make sure I'm not misinterpreting anything.

First, code for this is really simple, create a WinForms application with a DateTimePicker (Our project is in .net 4.0, but I tried creating it in .net 4.5, same problem). The picker itself has Custom format with "HH:mm" as format, and also ShowUpDown set to true.
It has a validation method as follows:

```
private void dateTimePicker1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Set a breakpoint on that row.

Make sure to have another control in the application so that you can tab out of the DateTimePicker to trigger validation.

Now, when in the program navigate your way to the DateTimePicker and enter something "202" in for example the hour-field. This will have it look like you have written 20 first, and when you write the second "2", it will be just the 2 in the field for now.

Now tab out of the DateTimePicker. This will trigger the validation breakpoint. Note how the value of the DateTimePicker now is a date set to 20 for hours. Let the line execute and watch the value of the DateTimePicker again. Now the value os 02 for hours instead (NOT(!!) the value of DateTime.Now)

So, somehow after setting the value to DateTime.Now, it changes value to what the previous unfinished value entered in the DateTimePicker.

How come it is like this, is there any way I can work around this?

Comment: Im using `windows 8`, and when it validates the value is `02` as it should be and when it sets it to `DateTime.Now` then it sets it to the current time. I cant recreate this.

Comment: Ok, then it must be fixed in Win8, I'm currently on Windows 7, and there it is easily reproducable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot repro this.  The Windows version matters a great deal, lots of common control quirks got fixed in later releases.  I'm on Windows 8.

It is however a common problem, these controls are picky about what you do to them when they fire an event.  They tend to have code in them that runs after they fired the event which may well invalidate what you did.  The Validating event is especially tricky because it is raised as a side-effect of the focus changing.  If the DTP didn't yet get that same notification then there's trouble.  Pretty typical event ordering trouble.  Do favor the Leave event if you are not actually using Validating to validate the data.

Sounds like a match.  A general solution to these kind of ordering problems is to run your code *after* the event has fired and code execution is no longer inside the control's code.  You can do so elegantly with the form's BeginInvoke() method.  The target runs after your program re-enters the message loop and the UI is back into a quiescent state.  Like this:

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now));
    }
```

Comment: I liked the idea with running my buissnes-logic after the validating event, but it still has some quirks in my production code. When validating, the value is "20", so my validation passes, but when the event from BeginInvoke hits, it has changed to "02" both in GUI and the value of it... which will not be good for my buissness-logic, which expects the value to be within a certain range. I am on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

During the Validating event, I see the behaviour explained by you, but once the validating event is completed, the value is set to `DateTime.Now`.

Assuming that you want it to set the value of the DateTimepicker control to `DateTime.Now` during the Validating event itself, I found that setting the value twice shows the value changed to `DateTime.Now` -

`dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;`

`dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Yeah, I have noticed the same, and it is my backup work-around, but the code itself is not very clean and also quite confusing. :)